# Post selected drop down list text in a span tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to post a selected drop down list value in a span tag which id is `num` , I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
function callAjax(){
var project = $('#project').val();
var dataall={'project':project};
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "page.php", // call your php file
        data: dataall, 
        success: function (data) {
           $('#num').text()= $('#project').val();
        }
});
}
```

Please note that the function `callAjax()` is used as the following :

```
<select name="project" id="project" onchange="callAjax()">
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#num').text($('#project').val());
```

**For getting text of selected drop down**

```
$('#num').text($('#project option:selected').html());
```

**OR**

```
$('#num').text($('#project').find('option:selected').html());
```

Comment: It worked, but it just displays the value (which is a number)!
I want to get the associated text